# ASP.NET Core - Is it possible to forecfully flush response headers?

Tags: asp.net-core

I'd like to send some Link: '' headers to the client as quickly as possible so the client browser can begin fetching resources ASAP. Is this possible to do in ASP.NET Core? Something like a  "Flush Current Headers" would be ideal. It'd also be a perk if headers could still be written after the existing ones have been flushed.

My current implementation is in a middle-ware, but other homes like in an action filter could also work.